# How to get the index of the first row that meets the conditions of a mask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [100, 1123, 123, 100, 1, 0, 1],
        'b': [1000, 11123, 1123, 0, 55, 0, 1],
    },
    index=range(100, 107)
)
```

And this is the expected output. I want to create column `c`:

```
       a      b      c
100   100   1000    NaN
101  1123  11123    NaN
102   123   1123    NaN
103   100      0    3.0
104     1     55    NaN
105     0      0    NaN
106     1      1    NaN
```

The mask that is used is:

```
mask = ((df.a > df.b))
```

I want to get the index of first row that `mask` occurs. I want to preserve the original index but get the `reset_index()` value. In this example the first instance of the mask is at index `3`.

I can get the first instance of the mask by this:

```
df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask, 'c'] = 'the first row'
```

But I don't know how to get the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

This code can be modified to search for the second and third items as well, not only first.

```
cond1 = df['a'] > df['b']
cond2 = df.groupby(cond1).cumcount().eq(0)
df.loc[cond1 & cond2, 'c'] = 'the first row'
```

df:

```
        a      b              c
100   100   1000            NaN
101  1123  11123            NaN
102   123   1123            NaN
103   100      0  the first row
104     1     55            NaN
105     0      0            NaN
106     1      1            NaN
```

If you are only looking for the first value, the following code may be simpler:

```
df.loc[df['a'].gt(df['b']).cummax().cumsum().eq(1), 'c'] = 'the first row'
```

---

**Updete Answer**

if you want only location of index, use following code:

```
cond1 = df['a'] > df['b']
idx = cond1.idxmax()
loc = df.index.get_loc(idx)
```

loc:

```
3
```

```
df.loc[df.index == idx, 'c'] = loc
```

df:

```
        a      b    c
100   100   1000  NaN
101  1123  11123  NaN
102   123   1123  NaN
103   100      0    3
104     1     55  NaN
105     0      0  NaN
106     1      1  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

The code below assesses each row of the dataframe using `.apply()`, and when the condition `a > b` is met, it returns the linear index of the row. The results are written to a new column `'c'`.

```py
df['c'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: df.index.get_loc(row.name) if row.a > row.b else np.NaN,
    axis=1
)
```

Result:

```py
    a    b     c
100 100  1000  NaN  
101 1123 11123 NaN  
102 123  1123  NaN  
103 100  0     3.0
104 1    55    NaN
105 0    0     NaN
106 1    1     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter with your condition and get the first result:

```
maskresult= [df[df.A > df.b].iloc[0]]
index = df.isin(maskresult).any(axis=1).idxmax()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on the index and slice the first item:

```
df.loc[df.index[mask][:1], 'c'] = 'the first row'
```

*NB. using `[:1]` instead of `[1]` to also work if there is no `True`.*

Output:

```
        a      b              c
100   100   1000            NaN
101  1123  11123            NaN
102   123   1123            NaN
103   100      0  the first row
104     1     55            NaN
105     0      0            NaN
106     1      1            NaN
```

If there was no match this would create an empty column:

```
        a      b    c
100   100   1000  NaN
101  1123  11123  NaN
102   123   1123  NaN
103   100      0  NaN
104     1     55  NaN
105     0      0  NaN
106     1      1  NaN
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I need the expected output. Maybe i didn't  make it clear in my question.